# C code explanation

Tags: c, shellcode

Could anybody help me explaining these lines of code?

```
char code[] = "paste your shellcode here";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int (*func)();
   func = (int (*)()) code;
   (int)(*func)();
}
```

Comment: Note: 1. it won't compile under `C99`; 2. in the last line the casting to `int` is redundant, `(*func)();` is enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that you have here is an example of how to create a function pointer to an arbitrary slice of data and then call it.

In a very simple sense we are allocating an array of bytes (char []) into which the binary shellcode payload is pasted, typically as escaped hex values.

This line, `int (*func)();`, declares a function pointer that will return an integer.  This is typical because most code will have some sort of integer based exit code returned in EAX.

This line, `func = (int (*)()) code;` casts the byte array code to be a function pointer and assigns it to 'func', the previously defined function pointer.

This line `(int)(*func)();` actually calls the shellcode, transferring execution to the first memory location in the byte array.

This code is actually extremely useful.  You wouldn't expect to find it used to exploit a system; instead this code is used to test out, debug and otherwise experiment with shellcode during development.  Using it you can simply paste in the shellcode that you are trying to test and then execute it.  This allows you to keep your shellcode very simple, excluding all of the typical requirements for a full standalone executable, yet still allowing you to test it without requiring that you identify a vulnerability to exploit.  In this way you can know if the code works without being distracted by the various that arise when trying to exploit actual code.

Comment: Thanks David, But why everything is declared as pointers ? first we declared function pointer and not a normal function. second making the array as another function pointer then assiging it to the first function pointer ! I am just confused of all these pointers :)

Comment: The reason that it must be declared as a function pointer is because we are NOT allowing C to create a function prolog/epilog.  Instead, we are pointing (function pointer) to an arbitrary location in memory (the byte array) and telling the compiler, "Trust me, there will be executable code there if you jump to it."

Comment: @DavidHoelzer And why are we not allowing C to create a new pro/epilog?

Comment: Remember that this C code is designed to allow you to test the shellcode.  I want it to run exactly as is, nothing added or changed.  Also, ultimately, even if I created an actual function, how will I then embed this binary payload into the body of that function?  Ultimately the function pointer will be necessary.  It would feel super messy to use inline assembly to chain together a string of defined bytes.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I was gonna suggest inline assembly, lol. I agree with you, however for the sake of discussion; Does it really matter whether or not the shellcode is "padded" with a pro/epilog? Aside from the obvious unwanted increase in payload size.

Comment: No, not really.  But it's definitely easier to drop the code in this way than it is to try to drop it into inline assembly.

Comment: I searched the web an found that one of the important aspects of function pointers is you can pass them to another function. one last questions -sorry for that- this int (*func)() declares the function and  this (int) (*func)() calls it ? does these () make this difference ? or we can simply call it by func() ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Googling for *["paste your shellcode here"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22paste%20your%20shellcode%20here%22)*? The <s>first</s> second (now that this question is first LOL) result returned is [Corelan Team's Exploit writing tutorial part 9: Introduction to Win32 shellcoding](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2010/02/25/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-9-introduction-to-win32-shellcoding/) where it's all explained:

[image: shellcode lab]

In a nutshell, it's merely a small utility C application to test shellcode that will be used later on in following parts of the tutorial for this same purpose. The rest is explained in the tutorial.

Comment: Actually I am already studying shellcoding from this article and need to understand it ! So I just copied it from there.

Comment: OK...got it. I will do in the next post !

Comment: It's true that it's a line by line discussion but it does feel like this teeters between groups.. This seems to be able to fit here or stack overflow or reverse engineering...  Just my 2 cents. :)

Comment: Makes sense. :)  I just know how frustrating it is to have questions killed when it's tough to find the perfect place to post them. :)