# Difference between running an assembly program and running the disassembled code in shellcode.c

Tags: c, assembly, shellcode

I am currently working on 'Pentester Academy's x86_64 Assembly Language and Shellcoding on Linux' course (www.pentesteracademy.com/course?id=7). I have one simple question that I can't quite figure out: what is the exact difference between running an assembly program that has been assembled and linked with `NASM` and `ld` vs. running the same disassembled program in the classic `shellcode.c` program (written below). Why use one method over the other?

As an example, when following the first method, I use the commands :

```
nasm -f elf64 -o execve_stack.o execve_stack.asm
ld -o execve_stack execve_stack.o
./execve_stack
```

When using the second method, I insert the disassembled shellcode in the `shellcode.c` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char code[] = \
"\x48\x31\xc0\x50\x48\x89\xe2\x48\xbb\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x53\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";

int main(void) {

    printf("Shellcode length: %d\n", (int)strlen(code));
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
    ret();

    return 0;
}
```

... and use the commands:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o shellcode shellcode.c
./shellcode
```

I have analyzed both programs in GDB and found that addresses stored in certain registers differ. I have also read the answer to the following question ([C code explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636540/c-code-explanation)), which helped me understand the way the shellcode.c program works. Having said that, I still don't fully understand the exact way in which these two methods differ.

Comment: there won't be much difference if you wrote good code, and followed the abi. You probably overlooked something

Comment: Maybe there was existing data in the registers that wasn't cleared properly, or your code messed up some of the callee-saved registers?

Comment: Please see screenshot https://plus.google.com/u/0/115019598668825244997/posts/QvbMtC4Vtqj illustrating an objdump of the x86-64 Assembly code in question, on the left, and gdb running shellcode with a break point at *&code, on the right. If you look around "movabs rbx,0x68732f2f6e69622f" , you'll see the encoded shellcode down to the "syscall".  I would expect significant diffs elsewhere. Your x86-64 is using _start vs main in the C prog, among things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no theoretical difference between the two methods. In both you end up executing a bunch of assembly instructions on the processor.

The `shellcode.c` program is there to just demonstrate what would happen if you run the assembly defined as an array of bytes in the `unsigned char code[]` variable.

> Why use one method over the other?

I think you don't understand the purpose of shellcodes and the reasoning behind the `shellcode.c` program (why it shows what happens when an arbitrary sequence of bytes **you have control on** is executed on the processor).

A shellcode is a small piece of assembly code that is used to exploit a software vulnerability. An attacker usually injects a shellcode into software by taking advantage of common programming errors such as [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and then tries to make the software execute that injected shellcode.

A good article showing a step-by-step tutorial on how to generate a shell by performing shellcode injection using buffer overflows can be found [here](https://dhavalkapil.com/blogs/Shellcode-Injection/).

Here is how a classic shellcode `\x83\xec\x48\x31\xc0\x31\xd2\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80` looks like in assembler:

```
sub esp, 72
xor eax, eax
xor edx, edx
push eax
push 0x68732f2f    ; "hs//" (/ is doubled because you need to push 4 bytes on the stack)
push 0x6e69622f    ; "nib/"
mov ebx, esp       ; EBX = address of string "/bin//sh"
push eax
push ebx
mov ecx, esp
mov al, 0xb        ; EAX = 11 (which is the ID of the sys_execve Linux system call)
int 0x80
```

In an x86 environment, this does an `execve` system call with the "/bin/sh" string as parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Valy, the referenced article from Dhaval Kapil was indeed very enlightening.

Comment: You're welcome! Basically, the `shellcode.c` program is only used so that you can test a shellcode which later on you would use in an exploit.